# Suggestions how to check for presence of a audio CD-ROM before continuing the script

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have found a nice solution to check if an audio cd is present. It works with a While loop which I like to end after the audio rip is done and the disc is ejected.

```
while true; do
    sleep 10
    cdparanoia -Q 2>&1 | grep 'audio only'
    RET=$?
    if [ $RET = "0" ] ; then
        abcde -c ~/Music/abcde.conf -o flac,mp3,ogg -p -x
    fi
done
```

Comment: Good work, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution to my wishes, hereby my code

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "voer componist in"
read componist
echo ingevoerde "$componist"

echo "voer het aantal CD's in"
read aantaldiscs
echo aantal discs $aantaldiscs

mkdir ~/Music/"$componist"
for a in $(seq -f %02g 01 $aantaldiscs);
do
mkdir ~/Music/"$componist"/$a
echo "OUTPUTDIR='~/Music/"$componist"/$a'" > ~/Music/abcde.conf
echo "OUTPUTFORMAT='\${TRACKNUM}.\${TRACKFILE}'" >> ~/Music/abcde.conf
echo "LAMEOPTS='-V 0'" >> ~/Music/abcde.conf
echo "FLACOPTS='-f --verify --best'" >> ~/Music/abcde.conf
echo "OGGENCOPTS='-q 8'" >> ~/Music/abcde.conf
echo "MAXPROCS=2" >> ~/Music/abcde.conf

echo "mungefilename ()" >> ~/Music/abcde.conf
echo "{" >> ~/Music/abcde.conf
echo "echo "$@" | sed s,:,\ -,g | tr / _ | tr -d \’\"\?\[:cntrl:\]" >> ~/Music/abcde.conf
echo "}" >> ~/Music/abcde.conf

    while true; do
        sleep 10
        cdparanoia -Q 2>&1 | grep 'audio only'
        RET=$?
        if [ $RET = "0" ] ; then
            abcde -c ~/Music/abcde.conf -o flac,mp3,ogg -p -x
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: When I use echo instead of abcde ripper it seems to work just fine. I think the problem is the "break" command that cancels the encoding process.

Comment: I think the decoding ends correctly now there where some minor issues with the abcde.conf file. Another issue I noticed is the OUTPUT directory, I put this between quotes because the system complained it couldn't find ~/Music/Grieg Edition/01 but is uses now ~/~/Music/Grieg Edition/01. I believe this is just a simple 'positioning error. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Perhaps it only complained because the directory already existed, its creats its directories by itself it seems I'll try that later.

Comment: It seems to put the directory there where I start the script. Perhepas I should try to chance the ~ into a variable which I can use for the location to store files?